# How to make wait the end of a DAG execution before starting an other one in Airflow?

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I would like to migrate my data into an other database. To do that I use Airflow to run a DAG composed of ETL flows. Each run is for one day of data and I have 3 years to catch-up. The problem is that each run has an unknown execution time and it's important to wait the end of the run before starting the next one.

I try to put a minimal schedule_interval and fix max_active_runs=1, but at the end not all data were loaded. A lot of days have jumped. I notice this Airflow comportment : at the end of the schedule interval, my program is partially executed (so my variable that give the date of the day to catch-up is incremented), then is stopped because of the max_active_runs.

```
with DAG(
        dag_id='catch_up',
        default_args={
            'owner': 'airflow',
            'start_date': datetime.now(),
            'depends_on_past': False,
            'retries': 1,
        },
        description=' ',
        schedule_interval=*/2 * * * *,
        max_active_runs=1,
        catchup=False

) as dag: 

    date = launch_date()
    start_etl = PythonOperator(
            task_id='flow',
            python_callable=launch_flow,
            op_args=[date]
    )

    ...
```

My question is how can I really make wait the end of the execution before starting an other one ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are after is a combination of `max_active_runs`, `depends_on_past` & `wait_for_downstream` (see [code base](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/fa2bec042995004f45b914dd1d66b466ccced410/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L500-L510))

> depends_on_past -  when set to true, task instances will run
> sequentially and only if the previous instance has succeeded or has been skipped. The task instance for the start_date is allowed
> to run.
>
> wait_for_downstream - when set to true, an instance of task
> X will wait for tasks immediately downstream of the previous instance
> of task X to finish successfully or be skipped before it runs. This is useful if the
> different instances of a task X alter the same asset, and this asset
> is used by tasks downstream of task X. Note that depends_on_past
> is forced to True wherever wait_for_downstream is used. Also note that
> only tasks *immediately* downstream of the previous task instance are waited
> for; the statuses of any tasks further downstream are ignored.

I think having :

```
default_args = {
    'wait_for_downstream': true,
    'depends_on_past': true, // (*) see note below
    ...

}

with DAG(
        default_args=default_args,
        max_active_runs=1,
        ...
) as dag: 
        ...
```

Will give you the logic you are after as only 1 active DagRun can be at any given time while each task must wait to the predecessor one in the previous run. On top of that if a specific task failed it will block everything and no new runs will be created till you address the issue manually.

Noting that since you didn't provide much details it may be that your use case can be solved by setting only `max_active_runs=1` and having `depends_on_past=True` on the last task, but once you understand the parameters it's easier to find the right config for you.

(*) technically there is no need to set `depends_on_past=True` when setting `wait_for_downstream=True` because [Airflow will override it for you](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/fa2bec042995004f45b914dd1d66b466ccced410/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L843-L844) but being explicit can help for readability.